# Change position of colorbar with plotly express heatmap

Tags: plotly

I would like to change the position of the colorbar to put it closer to the heatmap. Any ideas?

My code:

```py
data = heatmapData
fig3 = px.imshow(data,
                labels=dict(x="Mois de l'année", y="Types de Pollens", color="Grains moyen par m3"),
                x=['Février','Mars', 'Avril' ,'Mai' , 'Juin' ,'Juillet' ,'Août', 'Septembre'],
                y=['Aulne', 'Ambroisie', 'Armoise', 'Bouleau', 'Charme', 'Châtaignier',
       'Noisetier', 'Cupressacées', 'Hêtre',
       'Frêne', 'Graminées', 'Mûrier',
       'Olivier', 'Plantain', 'Platane', 'Peuplier', 'Chêne', 'Oseille',
       'Saule', 'Tilleul', 'Urticacées'],
                color_continuous_scale = "tempo",
                 
               )
fig3.update_xaxes(side="top")
fig3.update_layout(width=1000,    height=600)
fig3.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered to play with margins?

Comment: Thanks it helped !

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you achieved what you desired? What kinds of margin should impact that? I have changed some values in the margins, but the colorbar doesn't come closer to the image @rpanai

Comment: Hi Grabriel, do you have a reproducible example I can look at?

Comment: @rpanai Hi Rodrigo! I managed to shrink the image using the margins after all! Although it would be great to have the possibility to change inner margins (the ones between the plot and the bar) and the outer margins. Thanks a lot for the insight though!

Comment: I'm Roberto ;) Why don't you add the answer?